# Different output between python online compiler and mine offline

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import requests
import json

print(requests.__version__)
print(json.__version__)

headers = {
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Host': 'www.soraredata.com',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
     like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
  'Referer':'https://www.soraredata.com/player/17512868900934537680021886
     28460549415375229654518317941780411003457747672993',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}
req = requests.Request('GET', 
  'https://www.soraredata.com/api/players/info/
   1751286890093453768002188628460549415375229654518317941780411003457747672993', 
   headers=headers)
resp = requests.Session().send(req.prepare())
print(resp.status_code)
```

On programiz.com works fine, gives 200 as the status code.

[image]

But it does not work on my PC, even though the code is the same and even the packages versions. I even tried with different python versions, but it did not work out.

[image]

I can t understand why it does not return 200. I hope someone can illuminate me.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I tried to run it on a windows machine, but even on my linux it did not work

Comment: code is the same but computers are different - with differen IPs, different reputations (some servers may use `blacklists` to block access for some computers). And some servers may have complex method to detect bots/scripts. First you could check what you get in `resp.text` - maybe you get message which explains everything. It may need JavaScript or something else, or it may ask you to answer Captcha.

Comment: The documentation for the soraredata api suggests you need to authenticate, and your code doesn't seem to include any authentication. I'm not sure why it's working on programiz though.

Comment: I run it on my Linux and it works.

Comment: it works for me even if I remove Session and headers.

Comment: yes, resp.text asks me to answer a captcha. What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is happened because while you are running your program in programiz.com that it can load the req link that is player info.

And while you are running the same program in the application that can't load the req link (check your system it may be offline)

Comment: no, it is not offline. But thanks for the answer